# Given Joint pdf $f(x,y)=\frac{cy}{x}.$ Find the value of c.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have been given a joint pdf $f(x,y)=\frac{cy}{x}.$ I have to find the value of c. where $0<x<3$ and $0<y<\frac{x}{3}$. The problem occurs when I integrate $\frac{cy}{x}$ w.r.t $x$ over $0<x<3$ I have to evaluate $lnx$ over $0$ and $3$ limit which results in $ln(3)-ln(0)$ but $ln0$ is undefined. How do I proceed. Is there a mistake in my method. Please guide?

Comment: But why integrate wrt. $x$ first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the restriction $y<\frac   x 3$ which gives $x >3y$. So you have to integrate w.r.t $x$ from $3y$ to $3$ and then intergate w.r.t.  $y$ from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: still getting issue when integrate $y(ln3-ln3y) $w.r.t $y$ because the result involves evaluating limit of $y^{2}ln(3y)$ over $0$ and $1$ again $ln(0)$ comes in

Comment: $y\ln y \to 0$ as $y \to 0$. @Ameer786